# Including Armadillo C++ library in a C++ project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, libraries, armadillo

I'm trying to include the Armadillo C++ library, a linear algebra library, in a C++ project I'm working on, and I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to do so. I'm unfamiliar with how to add libraries to a project in general, so I've been searching for a resource that has step by step instructions, and the best one I could find didn't work for me (http://codeyarns.com/2013/11/15/how-to-use-armadillo-on-windows/). I followed all the instructions on the web page, and Visual Studio still complains when I put `#include <armadillo>` and `using namespace arma` in my code. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Look in the `examples` folder that comes with the Armadillo .tar.gz archive. It contains a readme file, and an example project for MSVC.

Comment: In your VS project, in the properties pages, add the full path to the armadillo include folder into the include path.  (And you might need to `#include "armadillo"`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have put all the .lib and .dll files in a directory which is added to the PATH system environment variable

[image]

and then you just have to add the correct include and library directories in VS2015
[image]

and add the lib dependencies you have
[image]

Comment: Hi @Claes Rolen, and everyone who has visited here on this post. 
How can I get all of the DLLs and libs files? I followed the link to the source code, but I could not find those files there.  
Do I need to use Cmake to rebuild the code for getting thems?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi @NguyenHai, if you download the Armadillo package it has OpenBLAS lib under ./example/lib_win64. OpenBLAS implements the BLAS and most important features from Lapack

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, even though this post has not been updated for a long time. I really appreciated it. I have downloaded the Armadillo latest package from http://arma.sourceforge.net/. I unpacked it on Windows, and only found libopenblas.dll and libopenblas.lib in the example folder. How may I get all of the blas_win64 or lapack_win64 dlls/libs like what you have in your answer ?

Comment: You don't need them anymore, OpenBLAS includes both. If you want to use BLAS and Lapack you can download an old Armadillo version where they are included e.g. 9.900.5 https://sourceforge.net/projects/arma/files/armadillo-9.900.5.tar.xz/download

Comment: Hi @Claes Rolen,

Thank you very much for your answer and your time. That is clear now. It works! The libopenblas.dll should be sufficient.